# Calculate trigonometric functions based on Tangent half-angle formula has special problem

Tags: trigonometry

At the moment i need to compute sine and cosine based of tangent function. To solving this problem, I found the [Tangent half-angle formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_formulafunction):
$$\sin {\alpha}= \frac{2 \tan{\frac{\alpha}{2}}}{1+\tan^2{\frac{\alpha}{2}}}$$
$$\cos {\alpha}= \frac{1- \tan^2{\frac{\alpha}{2}}}{1+\tan^2{\frac{\alpha}{2}}}$$
We cannot use it for compute $\sin \pi$ and $\cos \pi$(becouse $\tan \frac{\pi}{2}$ is it impossible).

How to modify this formulas for resolve this problem?

Comment: Is there some particular reason to use half-angle formulas? Seems like it would be easier to use $\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta=1$ and its relative $1+\tan^2\theta=\sec^2\theta$.

Answer (score 1):

In both cases the left and right limits as $\alpha\to\pi$ exist, so the formulas can be assumed to work in that sense.